# Can't connect to Polygon wallet via ethersjs on production: Error: unknown account #0 (operation="getAddress", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, polygon

I'm creating an application where the user should be able to connect their wallet to the Polygon network. It works on my local machine (localhost), but fails on production (the live site). This is the code:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []); const signer = provider.getSigner(); const userAddress = await signer.getAddress();
```

Again it works on localhost, but on production I'm getting the following error:

**"Uncaught (in promise) Error: unknown account #0 (operation="getAddress", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.7.2)"**

Using ethersjs v5.7.2. Any idea how to fix this?